# Horizontal scroll content in fixed width div

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

It is the mobile view. the width in the link div is 100%. I want to horizontally scroll the content of this div without scrolling the whole page. below is the html code.

```
          <div class="links">
            <ul>
              <li>Home</li>
              <li>Private Equity</li>
              <li>Venture Capital</li>
              <li>M&A</li>
              <li>Markets</li>
              <li>Industry</li>
              <li>Economy</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
```

and CSS

```
.links{
width: 100%

  ul{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;

    @media only screen and (max-width : 480px){
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
  }

  ul li{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding:8px 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: $roboto;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-stretch: condensed;
    line-height: 1;
    border-right:1px solid #000;

    &:last-child{
      border-right:0px;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is an `overflow-x: scroll` on your div: https://jsfiddle.net/m5k5Lkm4/

Also, I don't know what you're using to load your HTML, but if it's raw HTML, you'll need that & in "M&A" to be escaped as an HTML entity.

Comment: No problem!  I also want to note that the answer from @scaisEdge will also end up doing the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can add at your class

```
 .links {
     overflow: auto;
     overflow-y: hidden;
  ....
```